# how to implement a slide down on a click event with jquery

Tags: jquery

I know in jquery you can use toggle to display on and off. How do you get a slide down effect similar to what amazon has right now on the home page when you click expand?

Answer (score 1):

check [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) effect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it on Amazon, but you might be referring to this:

[slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

More effects built in can be seen [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)